# AndroidViewClient (Culebra) fails on Marshmallow

Tags: android, ubuntu, androidviewclient

I have made a script with the help of Culebra GUI on a rooted Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.2.

The test passes with success. However when I try to run the same script on a Moto X running Android 6.0 the script fails prematurely.

```
testSomething (__main__.CulebraTests) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: testSomething (__main__.CulebraTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sporza-test.py", line 58, in testSomething
    self.vc.dump(window=-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.4.0-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 3158, in dump
    raise RuntimeError('''ERROR: UiAutomator output contains no valid information. UiAutomator was killed, no reason given.''' + extraInfo)
RuntimeError: ERROR: UiAutomator output contains no valid information. UiAutomator was killed, no reason given.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.536s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Also on a Nexus 6P running Android 6.0.1 the same thing happens.

Does `dump` not work on Android Marshmallow?

In my testfile I have declared

```
'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True
```

Btw I'm running this on Ubuntu 15.10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested `AndroidViewClient`, `dump` and `culebra` and they all work as expected on Android 6.0.1. Try rebooting the device and running the tests again. Also, run `uiautomator dump` manually and see if it produces some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been discussed in https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/issues/175.